# Date format "\/Date(1394841600000)\/"?(In ticks)

Tags: javascript, sql, date

I retrieved a date from my database table which was of the format : `DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS.FFF` and saved it in a dynamic variable which was then passed to the JavaScriptSerializer class to make it a JSON object and I got the format: `"\/Date(1394841600000)\/"` for the date. I'm not sure why this is coming and I cant find this format in any of the standard date format lists.

Can anyone tell me what this format is? Or better, how to parse this to get my original format back using javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is date in ticks since midnight Jan 1, 1970 to the date of object.

To convert use:

```
var myDate = new Date("/Date(1394841600000)/".match(/\d+/)[0] * 1);
```

[Here is Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LXstg/)

Comment: @MklRjv glad if it help you, select any answer which is helpful for future visitors too :)

Answer (score 2):

The format is milliseconds from UNIX epoch. What you see is basically a JSON friendly variant of `new Date(1394841600000)`. For example try this:

```
var date = new Date(1394841600000);

console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

`var myDate = new Date(parseInt('/Date(1354348015481)/'.substr(6)));`